# Different http code in get(url).status_code and different one in get(url).history

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, url

`url='http://example.com/hey.php?redirect=http://example.com'` when I check the http status code of the above URL in python3 using code like `get(url).status_code` then it give `200` as the http code. But, when I type `get(url).history` it gives something like `[<Response [302]>]`. Can you explain to me this situation?!

Comment: We can't help without seeing the actual code you're using.  Please update the question to include a full sample program that we can run ourselves.

Comment: I can't give you the url. That was all I could do to explain you the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Even if you can't show us the url you're using, surely you can show us the rest of the code?  i.e. you're calling `get()`, but we don't know anything about that function.  Is it from the `requests` module?  Is it from some other package?  Is it a function you wrote yourself?

Comment: oh sorry. I forgot to mention ```from requests import *```

Comment: @krishnakumar That's just the module, we need more information than that. Why are you using `import *`, by the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked [requests documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.4/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history)? When you get the resource the server might say to your client like "Hey, today this resource can be found at another URL. Check that if you want". So your client goes to a new location and eventually reaches the needed resource.

If you want to trace such redirection you use `history` method of `request`. If you want to change the behavior of your client so that it now "does not want" to look for the resource at another suggested location, then you set `allow_redirects=False` in your `get` method parameter (which is `true` by default for get requeds).

In your case `[<Response [302]>]` means that following redirection is enabled and your client followed the redirection one time before reaching the required resource.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default `request.get()` behavior with redirected URLs.

If you request a URL that returns a redirect response, `requests.get()` will automatically follow the redirection.

`status_code` is the result of the final request, and `history` is all the redirect steps along the way.

If you don't want that behavior, use the `allow_redirects=False` keyword arg.